# how to do the addition of double data type value and int data type value in mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

here is my query

```
SELECT max_cet_percentage,agri_wg_total, (max_cet_percentage + agri_wg_total) as final_val
  FROM agri_table_name_before_weghtage_reupdate
  WHERE ApplicationNo LIKE '%30023'
```

and it's returning the result like this: `36.840515100000005`

expected result: `36.8405151`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use truncate to specify number of digits:

```
SELECT max_cet_percentage,agri_wg_total, truncate(max_cet_percentage + agri_wg_total, 7) as final_val
  FROM agri_table_name_before_weghtage_reupdate
  WHERE ApplicationNo LIKE '%30023'
```

Or you could use `round()`, `ceil()` or `floor()` if you want it to adjust the last digit.

Alternatively change the double column to have less digits after decimal:

```
Alter table tablename modify doubleColumn decimal(14, 7);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes it worked for me I changed the data type of double column to DECIMAL(10,7)

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad to hear that it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Truncate

```
SELECT max_cet_percentage,agri_wg_total, truncate((max_cet_percentage + agri_wg_total), 7) as final_val
  FROM agri_table_name_before_weghtage_reupdate
  WHERE ApplicationNo LIKE '%30023'
```

Comment: thanx for your answer